# How to add "+" or "-" in front of list elements when printing

Tags: python-3.x, list, append

I have a python code with several functions and I would like to add "+" or "-" in front of the printed list elements. For example, if I have the list `[5, 10, 60]`, and each of these numbers represents an action in my bank account.
So I want the print to look something like:

```
-5
-10
+60
```

so it is clear if I took out or recieved money from my bank.

I tried `list.append("+", cash)`, cash here representing a value from a function for adding money in my bank

```py
handling=[]

    elif valg==2:
        global cash
        cash=float(input("beløp: "))
        innskudd(cash)
        handling.append(cash)
    elif valg==5:
        print(handling)
```

when I tried the `.append("+", cash)`, I got an error message stating that only one element can be added at a time

Before I put the list - handling[] outside the function I only returned an empty list. I would also like to have the list inside the function if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your code to append a single element to the list, or go with string formatting.

Option 1: change `list.append('+', cash)` to

```
handling.append( '+' + str(cash) )
```

This converts `cash` to a string, concatenates it with `'+'` and appends the resulting string to the list.

Option 2: using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (available from Python 3.6, otherwise use @Heike's answer)

```
handling = [f'{i:+0.2f}' for i in cash_values]
```

Comment: If you use the first option, all elements in `handling` are turned into strings instead of numbers so  if you plan to do any other calculations with the numbers in `handling` I would use the second option and not format the numbers until you are actually printing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format` for this, e.g:

```
print([format(i, '+0.2f') for i in [20, 0.1, 0.5, -0.89]])

# output: ['+20.00', '+0.10', '+0.50', '-0.89']
```

You can read more about string formatting [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) support the same formatting operations, and were apparently designed to be faster.

Comment: Hi and thank you, I would not know before what elements in the list will be printed, only that the last 3 actions, or the last 3 added elements to the list will be printed. Is there a way to add the "+" as I add the element to the list?